# Create new matrix based on diagonal and antidiagonal of given matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to create matrix `B` from matrix `A`, with the following rules:

- Non-diagonal elements `A` are like non-diagonal elements of `B`.
- The main diagonal of `A` is the antidiagonal of `B`
- The antidiagonal of `A` is the main diagonal of `B`.

For example:

```
A = [ 1  2  3  4;
      7  8  9 10;
     13 14 15 16; 
     19 20 21 22 ];
B = [ 4  2  3  1;
      7  9  8 10;
     13 15 14 16;
     22 20 21 19 ];
```

How can I create `B` given `A`?

Answer (score 4):

You can create all of the indices, then it's a single assignment.

```
% Get size of square matrix A
n = size(A,1);
% Indicies are 1:n^2 by default
idx = 1:n^2;
% Swap diagonal and antidiagonal indices
idx( [1:(n+1):n^2, n^2-n+1:1-n:n] ) = [n^2-n+1:1-n:n, 1:(n+1):n^2];
% Use the indexing array to create B from A, reshape to be n*n
B = reshape( A( idx ), n, n );
```

Output for your example `A`:

```
B =
     4     2     3     1
     7     9     8    10
    13    15    14    16
    22    20    21    19
```

Comment: all the indices in one go ... nice one!

Comment: @Hoki thought there must be a way!

Answer (score 3):

There are so many ways to reach that results, it is just an indexing exercise. Here is one (of the many) way to reach that result for any *square* matrix of size `n`:

```
%% input
A=[ 1  2  3  4 ;
    7  8  9 10 ;
   13 14 15 16 ;
   19 20 21 22 ];

%% Calculate linear indices for the diagonal and antidiagonal
n=size(A,1) ;                   
idxdiag     = 1:(n+1):n^2 ;     % => idxdiag     = [1 6 11 16]
idxantidiag = n:(n-1):n^2-1 ;   % => idxantidiag = [4 7 10 13]

%% Generate B
B = A ;            % start with a simple copy (for the non-diagonal elements)

% Method 1: direct indice assignment
B(idxdiag)     = diag(fliplr(A)) ;  % Assign diagonal elements of B
B(idxantidiag) = flipud(diag(A)) ;  % Assign antidiagonal elements of B

% Method 2: summation
B([idxdiag idxantidiag]) = 0 ;
B = B + diag(diag(fliplr(A))) + fliplr(diag(diag(A))) ;

B =
     4     2     3     1
     7     9     8    10
    13    15    14    16
    22    20    21    19
```

Both methods return exactly the same matrix `B`.

---

I suggest you familiarise yourself with the MATLAB function used to understand what is going on behind the scene:

- [`fliplr`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fliplr.html)
- [`flipud`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipud.html)
- [`diag`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html)

and may be have a read at:
[Matrix Indexing in MATLAB](https://mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer and for links. I didn't have an information about fliplr and flipud. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I thought a little differently and came to a conclusion

```
A=[1 2 3 4;7 8 9 10;13 14 15 16; 19 20 21 22];;
n=size(A,1) ;
B=zeros(n,n) ;

for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        if i==j
            B(i,j)=A(i,n-i+1);
        elseif j==n-i+1
            B(i,j)=A(i,i);
        else
            B(i,j)=A(i,j);
        end
    end 
end
B
```

Comment: It's always good to use simple loops when you need to make something work. If you want something to work *well* in MATLAB, you'll usually find using vectorisation is much quicker! Both mine and Hoki's solutions are vectorised, and likely quicker - not an issue if your real application is only 4*4 matrices though.

Comment: @ Wolfie , thanks .That's right, your answers were efficient And I use them.
But I'm not familiar with such Conmmands. What is the best source that I can read and get familiar with these commands?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a loop. 10 years ago this loop would have been 100 or 1000 times slower than the corresponding vectorized code, now it is maybe 5 or 10 times slower only. That's typically not a big deal. If you find the code is too slow for your needs, that is the time to find a vectorized approach. -- Learning all the functions that exist and how to use them efficiently is something that comes with experience. Come here often, read questions and answers, apply what you learn, then bit by bit it gets easier and easeir.

Comment: I completely agree with @Cris, I didn't mean to put down your answer - glad you solved it yourself! Emphasis on my comment should have been **It's always good to use simple loops when you need to make something work** :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a variant using [`eye`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eye.html), [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html), and [`flip`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html) to generate [linear indices](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#d120e1301):

```
ind1 = find(eye(size(A)));
ind2 = flip(find(flip(eye(size(A)))));
B = A;
B([ind1 ind2]) = B([ind2 ind1]);

B =

     4     2     3     1
     7     9     8    10
    13    15    14    16
    22    20    21    19
```

And here's a variant of the above that uses just `eye` and `flip` to generate [logical indices](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#d120e1410):

```
ind1 = eye(size(A), 'logical');
ind2 = flip(ind1);
B = A;
B(ind1) = flip(A(ind2));
B(ind2) = flip(A(ind1));

B =

     4     2     3     1
     7     9     8    10
    13    15    14    16
    22    20    21    19
```